# Docker Compose: Stop "depends_on" service when "parent" finishes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to tell docker compose to kill services specified on the `depends_on` array, after the parent service test finishes without using `--abort-on-container-exit`?

I'm trying to build a docker file that runs tests from multiple apps, something like:

```
services:
  test-spa:
    build:
      context: ./spa
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: ["yarn", "run", "test", "--watch", "false"]
  lint:
    build:
      context: ./spa
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: ["yarn", "run", "lint"]
  build:
    build:
      context: ./spa
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: ["yarn", "run", "build", "--prod"]
  test-backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    entrypoint: [scripts/entrypoint.sh]
    command: bundle exec rails test
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Problem is `test-backend` starts up `db` service as a dependency, runs its tests, quits and `db` never finishes.

Using `--abort-on-container-exit` is not an option since `spa` related services might exit before `test-backend` is over.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a shell script. It would be trivial to write. This isn't a feature of docker-compose, and if you transition to swarm mode, you'll find that depends_on is no longer supported. It never really did what people expected anyway. See all the notes here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: Yes! We have some shell scripts that allow us to run the test suit on the CI. Was just wondering if there was a native way to kill a service when another service finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe this is a built in feature of docker-compose. But you can easily script a solution, e.g.:

```
docker-compose up -d db
docker-compose up test-backend
docker-compose down db
```

Outside of docker-compose, there's also the `docker container wait` command that lets you hang until a container exits. You can lookup the container name with a `docker container ls` and filters on a label or other unique value, or you can rely on the predictable container names from compose (`$project_$service_$replica`). The `docker container wait` command would allow you to spin up the entire project in a detached state and then wait for one container to exit before proceeding to stop it, e.g.:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker container wait $(basename $(pwd))_test-backend_1
docker-compose down db
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner useful when using docker compose for development. It starts an app(with dependencies) and when you hit `ctrl+c` it stops all services;

```
docker-compose up app; docker-compose stop
```